# Lost a table after sp_rename in SQL Server with unnecessary schema name in second parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have executed the following SQL-script to rename a table:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.OriginalTable', 'dbo.TableWithNewName'
```

I know now this is incorrect and that the value of the second parameter should be `TableWithNewName`. 
But now I can't find either of those tables and don't know how to fix this.

Comment: The table's new name is actually `[dbo].[dbo.TableWithNewName]` if we fully escape it, so to rename it to what it should be, use `EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[dbo.TableWithNewName]', 'TableWithNewName'`.

Comment: I just noticed it in the list of tables, you are correct. If you add this as an answer i can give you credit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script 
`SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Dbo.%'` you will find the table which u renamed earlier. U can rename the table as it is previous

```
EXEC SP_RENAME '[dbo.TableWithNewName]','TableWithNewName'
```

Comment: @Make sure before renaming the table it will impact on dependent table objects